# WinAPI creating button in console subsystem

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i have app that manipulates console, i want to make custom console buttons(minimize maximize close) i removed titlebar, but phind, chatgpt, bing, bard, cant do what i want
code:

```
#include <windows.h>

void MoveToCenter()
{
    RECT rectClient, rectWindow;
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rectClient);
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rectWindow);
    int posx, posy;
    posx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - (rectWindow.right - rectWindow.left) / 2;
    posy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - (rectWindow.bottom - rectWindow.top) / 2;

    MoveWindow(hWnd, posx, posy, rectClient.right - rectClient.left, rectClient.bottom - rectClient.top, TRUE);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();

    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU)); 
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED); 
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA); 
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

    MoveToCenter();

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Create a button
    HWND button = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",          // predefined class
        "Press me",        // button text
        WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // styles
        100,               // x position
        100,               // y position
        100,               // button width
        30,                // button height
        NULL,              // no parent window
        NULL,              // no menu
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), // instance handle
        NULL               // nothing to pass to WM_CREATE
    );


    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

that one draws button outside console but all my attempts to get clicks on it is useless, its just simply dont work, im already thinking about imgui

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: i want to make custom console, like modern cool console, ik i can try imgui, or c#, but thats the point of make this in c++

Comment: What you're trying to implement is called a *"Console Host"*. [Windows Command-Line: Introducing the Windows Pseudo Console (ConPTY)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/) covers pretty much everything you need to know.

Comment: @IInspectable I bow to superior knowledge :) (happens with you almost all the time!)

Answer (score 0):

Funny idea?
For this to work, your button must be like the console's parent and it must have the WM_CHILD style. Which give :

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();

    HWND button = CreateWindow(
        "BUTTON",          // predefined class
        "Press me",        // button text
        WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD,  // styles
        100,               // x position
        100,               // y position
        100,               // button width
        30,                // button height
        hWnd,              // parent window
        NULL,              // no menu
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), // instance handle
        NULL               // nothing to pass to WM_CREATE
    );

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) Plot spoiler: No, it isn't, not here.